# Filter out 2 files from a directory which slightly differ in file name but have same extension and pass to function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way in Python to iteratively select 2 files (which differ slightly) from a directory and pass to a function?

**For example :**

```
filename1 : file1_aaa.txt
filename2 : file1_bbb.txt

filename3 : file123_aaa.txt
filename4 : file123_bbb.txt

filename5 : 1_text_aaa.txt
filename6 : 1_text_bbb.txt
```

I have to iterate in the folder and select filename1 and filename2 since it has similar filename(difference only exists after underscore), pass it to a function. Then, I will iterate in the folder again and select filename3 and filename4 and again pass to a function. Is there a pythonic way to do that?

Comment: `glob.glob("file1_*.txt")`

Comment: Pythonic way to do what exactly? It is not clear from your question what you are asking. How to iterate a directory? How to iterate in couples? checkout [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)

Comment: Hi @Tomerikoo, i meant how to iterate through files in folder and select files like there in example and pass them to a function. Question is quite straightforward!!!

Comment: Apparently it is not. Is it random? Just any 2 files? Is it the files with the same prefix `filex`? Are there always just `aaa` and `bbb` for each prefix?

Comment: I have tried to build an example to make it simple. I am not sure how it complicates it. Let me try to make it clear in the question itself. Hope this removes the negative marking from the question.

Comment: Hi @Tomerikoo, I have tried to make my question clear. To answer your question, it is not random and yes just 2 files... Yes files will have same prefix say ```filex``` or ```123_filex```. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: So what distinguishes the couples is everything before the last `_`? What happens if there are 3 files, for example: `1_text_aaa.txt`, `1_text_bbb.txt` and `1_text_ccc.txt`? What would you expect to happen here?

Comment: Yes, what differentiates the files is everything before the last _. There will not be a situation that the directory has 3 files like you mentioned. It will either be "aaa" or "bbb". Now I get your confusion. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

def my_func(dir_list):
    for list in dir_list:
        print(list)

dir_files = os.listdir('path/to/dir/name')

# dir_files = ["file1_aaa.txt", "file1_bbb.txt", "file123_aaa.txt", "file123_bbb.txt", "1_text_aaa.txt", "1_text_bbb.txt"]
dirs_dict = {}
for dir in dir_files:
    cur_key = dir.split("_")[0]
    if cur_key in dirs_dict.keys():
        dirs_dict[cur_key].append(dir)
    else:
        dirs_dict[cur_key] = [dir]

for dirs_list in dirs_dict.values():
    my_func(dirs_list)
```

Note 1 - in my opinion, the example is still insufficient and the answer is still may be over fitted to the example.

Note 2 - the selection was based upon the suffix that precede the first `_` char. which means in your example to `1`, `file1` and `file123`

Note 3 - you can change the `cur_key` variable to choose which part of the file will be the key of the separation between all files

**another option to implement would be:**

```
import os
from itertools import groupby

def my_func(dir_list):
    for list in dir_list:
        print(list)

dir_files = os.listdir('path/to/dir/name')

# dir_files = ["file1_aaa.txt", "file1_bbb.txt", "file123_aaa.txt", "file123_bbb.txt", "1_text_aaa.txt", "1_text_bbb.txt"]
grouped = [list(v) for i,v in groupby(dir_files, lambda x: x.split("_")[0])]

for dirs_list in grouped:
    my_func(dirs_list)
```

much cleaner, shorter, one-liner version using `groupby` from `itertools`, with no need to declare dict in the middle

Comment: Hi @Yossi Levi, your solution works perfectly but using for loop may not work in my case as I do not know how many such files will be there in the directory. Also, I have added few more examples to my question, so requesting you to have a look!!!

Comment: edited to work with the edited question. hope you find this one helpful for you, pay attention that if not for all your examples - you must change the `cur_key` variable according to your requirements upon the full files list

Comment: Thanks @Yossi Levi, with little modification, I am able to use your code.

Comment: ohh, awesome... This groupby logic is really good. Thank you for sharing.